# Pythonic way to return freqencies by filtering non-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use a list of values to sub-set a pandas column and get frequencies on this sub-setted column.
The DataFrame fuelco uses the default RangeIndex.  The column `make` has been mapped from dtype of "object" to "category".

My first attempt using `[]` and .isin() method fails with a KeyError.

```
makes = ["Ford",
         "Tesla",
         "BMW",
         "Toyota"]
print(fuelco[fuelco["make"]].isin(makes).value_counts())

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Alfa Romeo', 'Ferrari', 'Dodge', 'Dodge', 'Subaru', 
'Subaru', 'Subaru',\n       'Toyota', 'Toyota', 'Toyota',\n       ...\n       'Saab', 
'Saturn', 'Saturn', 'Saturn', 'Saturn', 'Subaru', 'Subaru',\n       
'Subaru', 'Subaru', 'Subaru'],\n      dtype='object', length=39101)] are in the [columns]"
```

If I subset the DataFrame with logical comparisons, I get the expected results:

```
subset = fuelco[(fuelco.make == "Ford") |
               (fuelco.make == "Tesla") |
               (fuelco.make == "BMW")   |
               (fuelco.make == "Toyota") 
               ]
print(subset.make.value_counts())

Ford      3208
Toyota    1976
BMW       1807
Tesla       46
Name: make, dtype: int64
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to get the same results by using a list of values?

Comment from @cs95 below is the solution:

```
fuelco.loc[fuelco["make"].isin(makes), 'make'].value_counts()
Ford      3208
Toyota    1976
BMW       1807
Tesla       46
```

Comment: You have a misplaced `]`. You need to slice with the `.isin` mask: `fuelco[fuelco["make"].isin(makes)].value_counts()`

Comment: Can u add some sample input & expected output.

Comment: ```fuelco[fuelco["make"].isin(makes)].value_counts()``` returns:         ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'```

Comment: try `fuelco.loc[fuelco["make"].isin(makes), 'make'].value_counts()` instead

Comment: Thanks @cs95!  That works.  The [ ] indexing makes more sense by explicitly identifying the target column, fuelco['make].